# Set autofocus on Laravel input field using Form::text

Tags: html, laravel

How do I set `autofocus` on a certain field using the Form?

I have managed to set focus by registering the macro, but is it possible to set it in `Form::text`?

Comment: Edited the question, cannot answer my own question for 8 hours, sorry to bother you guys... Still, someone may find this useful...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is enough just to pass a third parameter in Form::text as array with 'autofocus'=>'autofocus'.

Sorry to bother you guys, maybe someone finds it useful.

Comment: Actually, it's just enough to pass the third parameter as `'autofocus'`

Comment: Both the original answer and this comment are correct. However, if you are using an associative array as the third argument for Form::text already (say, if you are passing a class in), then you will have to use the associative array.

Answer (score 2):

You can not go around it just by that you should set the second parameter that is "value" of the input to something if you don't want you should pass null there and it'll look like below:

```
{{Form::text('username', null, array('autofocus'=>'autofocus'))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As JoshP pointed out, you can just use 'autofocus' as the third parameter:

```
Form::text('email', 'user@gmail.com', array('autofocus'))
```